# System.Data.Oracle not found

Tags: c#, oracle, namespaces

I can't find the `System.Data.OracleClient` namespace in `Visual Studio 2010`,
when I tape using `System.Data.OracleClient`, it shows an error like if does not exits, and I can't find its reference.

Answer (score 0):

Under `System.Data` there is nothing called `OracleClient` unless you have installed Oracle client tools (OR) ODP on your machine. By default that dll won't be present. Do you rather mean `System.Data.SqlClient`?

You should be using `System.Data.OleDb` or `System.Data.Odbc` namespaces instead for working with `Oracle` database.

Comment: OleDb for Access and Odbc ?

Comment: @CarToUchE, NO, `oledb` is not only for Access, you can connect and work with Oracle Db as well. See here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308448

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to that assembly to your project. Right click 'References' node in your project in the solution explorer window, click Add Reference in the context menu. Find the assembly (System.Data.OracleClient) in the Assemblies tab, tick the box next to it and click ok.

[image: Solution explorer - Add Reference...]

[image: System.Data.OracleClient assembly in Assemblies]

Comment: That's possible only if you have installed Oracle client

Comment: @Rahul I do have it by default.

Comment: You have it cause most probably you have the oracle client installed on your machine (or) you have installed ODP. Else, default that dll won't be present. Again check this MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx which says *types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the .NET Framework.*

Comment: @Rahul not at all, I have freshly installed VS2015 CE on my machine and I do not have oracle client installed.